# Firebase Auth and Facebook Share Dialog on the web

Tags: firebase, facebook, flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

According to Facebook documentation, you can get the status of a Share Dialog if the user is logged into the Facebook app:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

> Note that response.error_message will appear only if someone using your app has authenticated your app with Facebook Login.

It seems to work fine for me when I use their JS SDK directly. However, when I sign in via Firebase Auth, the response is always null. Is there a trick to making it work with Firebase Auth on the web?

Comment: Where did you read you can get the status? And what are you going to do with the status?

Comment: response.error_message basically tells me if sharing was successful or not

Comment: That will tell you if an error happened. Not if they posted or not. And you didn't answer my second question

Comment: @WizKid Correct. I need to know if an error happens or not. It only does that if you use facebook login. Doesn't work for Firebase for some reason.

Comment: Again. Why do you need to know?

Comment: @WizKid To figure out if the user successfully shared the material or not. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you need to know if they shared it or not?

Comment: In case you wanted to “reward” users for sharing in any way, shape or form, please be aware that that is not allowed. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-developer-policy-3.2

Comment: Noted, will avoid using FB SDK directly